# Select latest record with some more conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, record

```
ID    Level Effective Date  ExpirationDate
000012-12     2 12/01/2005  NULL
000012-12    1    12/01/2005  NULL
000012-12    2    12/01/2005  01/01/2009
000012-A12    2 10/01/1994  11/30/2005
000012-A12    2 01/01/1999  11/30/2005
000012-A12    2 09/01/2001  11/30/2005
000012-A12    1 12/01/2005  12/31/2007
```

Only most current Records will be fetched. It means in the above scenario
Exp date - If `null` the record is still active.
           If greater then current time stamp, its future exp date , which means still active.
           If less then current time stamp , then terminated.
Most current is the most active or latest terminated record. If it has active and terminated then only active will be shown. Else last terminated record.

One ID can have 2 rows for same effective date and exp date but multiple levels. So in that case we would need to select only 1 record for level one.

So as per the data set above below is the intended output

Output

```
000012-12    1   12/01/2005  NULL
000012-A12  2   12/01/2005  01/01/2009
```

Please help

Thomas. Please look into the following data set.

```
Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000872-A24',1,'1994-10-01',NULL); 
Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000872-A24',1,'1999-01-01',NULL);  
Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000872-A24',2,'2001-09-01',NULL ); 
Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000872-A24',1,'2003-01-01','2007-12-31');
```

When you run the query it should give

> 000872-A24    2   09/01/2001  NULL

but now it returns

> 000872-A24    1   01/01/2003  12/31/2007

Comment: @sqllearner190 - Does the table have a primary key such as an auto_increment or identity column?

Comment: @sqllearner190 - Can you demonstrate in your sample data a situation that would require the second condition of item #2 in your requirement list?

Comment: Thats what i was thinking. Because when they ask for latest record, it should always give 1 out of the bunch ..and then that will not have any dependency on level..BUt still how do i choose most current record ( based on expiration date)

Comment: @sqllearner190 - We need more info to provide a reasonable answer. Have posted an answer which posits some of those questions.

Comment: Thomas,
I justa  got a clarification on requirement.
below is the scenario
ID Level Effective Date ExpirationDate
000012-12 2 12/01/2005 NULL
000012-12 1 12/01/2005 NULL
000012-12 2 12/01/2005 01/01/2009
000012-A12 2 10/01/1994 11/30/2005
000012-A12 2 01/01/1999 11/30/2005
000012-A12 2 09/01/2001 11/30/2005
000012-A12 1 12/01/2005 12/31/2007

i need to choose the most current record which would be on exp date..if null then choose that one..if we have more then one record who has same effective date and expiration date, then choose level one. I gotta do that for all the Ids

Comment: @sqllearner - Please update your original post with any new information.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to provide an answer without knowing the database product.

```
1. if there is no auto_increment/identity column 
2. and if there is no other primary key (which is a bad idea obviously) 
3. and if the given database product supports `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (each DBMS will likely have some equivalent to the current date and time) 
4. and if the target date by which you measure "latest" is the current date and time


Select Id, Level
From Table As T
Where T. EffectiveDate =    (
                            Select Max(T2.EffectiveDate)
                            From Table As T2
                            Where T2.ID = T.ID
                                And ( T2.EffectiveDate Is Null
                                    Or (
                                        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= T2.EffectiveDate
                                        And CURRENT_TIMESTAMP <= T2.ExpirationDate
                                        )
                                    )
                            )
```

You will note a number of caveats in my answer. That is an indicatation that we need more information:

1. What database product and version?
2. Is there an auto_incrementing, unique key on the table?
3. How does the Level fit into the results you want? (Please expand your sample data to include edge cases).
4. What should happen if the current date and time is prior to the effective date that has a null expiration date?

**EDIT**

Now that we know you are using SQL Server 2008, that makes the solution easier:

```
If object_id('tempdb..#Test') is not null
    Drop Table #Test;
GO
Create Table #Test (
                    PkCol int not null identity(1,1) Primary Key
                    , Id varchar(50) not null
                    , Level int not null
                    , EffectiveDate datetime not null
                    , ExpirationDate datetime null
                    );

Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000012-12',2,'12/01/2005',NULL);
Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000012-12',1,'12/01/2005',NULL); 
Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000012-12',2,'12/01/2005','01/01/2009');
Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000012-A12',2,'10/01/1994','11/30/2005');
Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000012-A12',2,'01/01/1999','11/30/2005');
Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000012-A12',2,'09/01/2001','11/30/2005');
Insert #Test( Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate ) Values ('000012-A12',1,'12/01/2005','12/31/2007');

With Items As
    (
    Select PkCol, Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate
        , Row_Number() Over (   Partition By Id
                                Order By EffectiveDate Desc, Coalesce(ExpirationDate,'99991231') Desc, Level Asc ) As Num
    From #Test
    )
Select PkCol, Id, Level, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate
From Items
Where Num = 1
```

In your sample output, you have the combination `('000012-A12',2,'12/01/2005','01/01/2009')` which does not appear in your original data.

I'm using two features that were added in SQL Server 2005: common-table expressions and ranking functions. The common-table expression `Item` acts like a in-place view or query. The ranking function `Row_Number` is where the real magic happens. As the name implies, it returns a sequential list of numbers ordered by the `Order By` clause. However, it also restarts numbering for each Id value (that's the `Partition By` bit). By filtering on `Num = 1`, I'm returning the "top" value for each Id.

Comment: Thomas,
I justa  got a clarification on requirement.
below is the scenario
ID Level Effective Date ExpirationDate
000012-12 2 12/01/2005 NULL
000012-12 1 12/01/2005 NULL
000012-12 2 12/01/2005 01/01/2009
000012-A12 2 10/01/1994 11/30/2005
000012-A12 2 01/01/1999 11/30/2005
000012-A12 2 09/01/2001 11/30/2005
000012-A12 1 12/01/2005 12/31/2007

i need to choose the most current record which would be on exp date..if null then choose that one..if we have more then one record who has same effective date and expiration date, then choose level one. I gotta do that for all the Ids in tbl

Comment: @sqllearner190- You should update your original post with the revised sample data. What about the other questions (db version, auto_incrementing/identity column, target date used for comparison)?

Comment: Thomas, i have updated the requirement. Kindly help.the table has identity column too.

Comment: wowww...what did u do ! That seems to be very advanced level SQL programming.. :-) ..Can you explain the code a lil bit..

Comment: @Thomas -  I have updated my question .The logic does not work for the set of values i have provided in there.

Comment: Thanks. I just changed the sequence of order by clause and it worked.
Thank you so much for your help .